# How can I get the python path modified for all ipython notebooks run from a given instance of jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am packaging some software for internal distribution as a zip file containing python modules and some required binaries.

I need an easy way for users to launch jupyter notebook and have the python modules added to their python path and for module setup command to specify the location of the binaries.

I have created a bat file that runs jupyter-notebook from the zip file and specifies that it should use the 'notebook' directory within the zip file.

`jupyter-notebook notebook`

Adding a file, ipython_config.py, to the notebook directory lets me specify commands to be run for each notebook in the 'notebook' directory. This works perfectly, the sys.path is modified and binary locations are specified for the python modules. I can't see how to apply the same setting to notebooks created in subdirectories of 'notebook'.

How can I require that Jupyter notebook runs a specified file for all ipython notebooks it creates? I can't find any Jupyter config options that specify configuration for IPython notebooks.

Note that it's critical that the user's ipython settings are not changed, all configuration must be performed by the bat file using data within the zip file I am distributing.